# C++ Sockets Segmentation Fault When Client Attempts to Connect to the Server

Tags: c++, sockets, posix

I am attempting to make a multithreaded program that uses interprocess communication to calculate entropies. I keep running into a segmentation fault in my program whenever clients attempt to connect to the server and cannot find the source of the issue. If anyone can find the bug I would really appreciate it.

EDIT:
I updated the server and client files to address the issues in the comments but still receive a segmentation fault when the client connects to the server. Did I implement these changes incorrectly? Or is there another bug causing the segmentation fault?

Changes:

- first read on server gets string size and second copies gets the string as a char array
- instead of writing/reading the entropy array, I sent them as individual double values and saved them to a vector on the client
- removed auxiliary accept()

client.cpp

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

struct threadInfo
{
    std::string str;
    int cpu;
    int port;
    char host[64];
    std::vector<double> entropies;
};

void *threadFunction(void *t_void_ptr)
{
    struct threadInfo * t_ptr = (threadInfo *) t_void_ptr;
    
    int sockfd, portno, n, i;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t_ptr->str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(t_ptr->str[i]))
            x++;
    }
    
    portno = t_ptr->port;
    
    // Create the socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR opening socket" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    server = gethostbyname(t_ptr->host);
    if (server == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR, no such host" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    // Populate sockaddr_in structure
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    
    // Start a new connection
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR connecting" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    
    // Send size of scheduling info string
    int msgSize = sizeof(t_ptr->str);
    n = write(sockfd, &msgSize, sizeof(int));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR writing to socket" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    
    // Send the scheduling information
    n = write(sockfd, &t_ptr->str, sizeof(&t_ptr->str));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR writing to socket" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    
    // Receive the entropies from server<double> entropy
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        double entropy;
        n = read(sockfd, &entropy, sizeof(double));
        if (n < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "ERROR reading from socket" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        t_ptr->entropies.push_back(entropy);
    }
        
    close(sockfd);
    
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct std::vector<threadInfo> info;
    
    // Check command line arguments
    if (argc != 3)
    {
       std::cerr << "usage " << argv[0] << " hostname port" << std::endl;
       exit(0);
    }
    
    // Read from input file via input redirection
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    std::string buffer;
    int cpu = 1;
    while (getline(std::cin, buffer))
    {
        strings.push_back(buffer);
    }
    
    // Fill in info vector
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
    {
        info[i].str = strings[i];
        info[i].cpu = cpu++;
        info[i].port = atoi(argv[2]);
        strcpy(info[i].host, argv[1]);
    }
    
    // Create nThreads to access the server
    pthread_t tid[strings.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&tid[i], nullptr, threadFunction, &info) != 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Thread not created" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    // Join threads
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], nullptr);
    }
    
    // Output information
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
    {
        int j;
        std::vector<char> task;
        std::vector<int> extraFreq;
        for (int j = 0; j < strings[i].length(); j++)
        {
            if (isalpha(strings[i][j]))
                task.push_back(strings[i][j]);
            else if (isdigit(strings[i][j]))
            {
                int d = 1;
                while (isdigit(strings[i][j+d]))
                    d++;
                std::string s = strings[i].substr(j,d);
                std::cout << s << std::endl;
                extraFreq.push_back(stoi(s));
                j += d - 1;
            }
        }
        
        std::cout << "CPU " << i+1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Task scheduling information: ";
        for (j = 0; j < info[i].entropies.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            std::cout << task[j] << "(" << extraFreq[j] << "), ";
        }
        std::cout << task[j] << "(" << extraFreq[j] << ")" << std::endl ;
        std::cout << "Entropy for CPU " << info[i].cpu << std::endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < info[i].entropies.size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << info[i].entropies[j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

server.cpp

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>


// Structure to accomplish entropy algorithm
struct entropy
{
    std::vector<double> currH;
    std::vector<char> currTask;
    std::vector<int> extraFreq;
    std::map<char, int> freqArr;
};

// Fireman function to eliminate zombie processes
void fireman(int)
{
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    signal(SIGCHLD, fireman);

    // Check the commandline arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Port not provided" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    // Create the socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening socket" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    // Populate the sockaddr_in structure
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    // Bind the socket with the sockaddr_in structure
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error binding" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    // Set the max number of concurrent connections
    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while(true)
    {
        // Accept a new connection
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, (socklen_t *)&clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error accepting new connections" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            // Get message size from client
            int n;
            int msgSize = 0;
            n = read(newsockfd, &msgSize, sizeof(int));
            if (n < 0)
            {
                std::cerr << "Error reading from socket" << std::endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            
            // Read input from client
            char *tempBuffer = new char[msgSize + 1];
            bzero(tempBuffer, msgSize + 1);
            n = read(newsockfd, &tempBuffer, sizeof(msgSize + 1));
            if (n < 0)
            {
                std::cerr << "Error reading from socket" << std::endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            std::string temp = tempBuffer;
            delete[] tempBuffer;
            
            // Convert to entropy struct and initialize values
            struct entropy x;
            for (int j = 0; j < msgSize + 1; j++)
            {
                if (isalpha(temp[j]))
                    x.currTask.push_back(temp[j]);
                else if (isdigit(temp[j]))
                {
                    int d = 1;
                    while (isdigit(temp[j+d]))
                        d++;
                    char s[msgSize + 1];
                    memcpy(s, &temp[j], d );
                    std::cout << s << std::endl;
                    x.extraFreq.push_back(atoi(s));
                    j += d - 1;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < x.currTask.size(); j++)
            {
                x.freqArr[x.currTask[j]] = 0;
                x.currH.push_back(0);
            }
                
            //Calculate entropies
            int currFreq = 0;
            int newFreq = 0;
            double currTerm = 0;
            double newTerm = 0;
            double H = 0;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < x.currTask.size(); i++)
            {
                newFreq = currFreq + x.extraFreq[i];
                
                // Entropy algorithm
                if (newFreq == x.extraFreq[i])
                    H = 0;
                else
                {
                    if (x.freqArr[x.currTask[i]] == 0)
                    {
                        currTerm = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currTerm = x.freqArr[x.currTask[i]] * log2(x.freqArr[x.currTask[i]]);
                    }
                    newTerm = (x.freqArr[x.currTask[i]] + x.extraFreq[i]) * log2(x.freqArr[x.currTask[i]] + x.extraFreq[i]);
                    
                    H = log2(newFreq) - ((log2(currFreq) - H) * (currFreq) - currTerm + newTerm) / newFreq;
                }
                
                // Update frequency map
                if (x.freqArr[x.currTask[i]] != 0)
                {
                    x.freqArr[x.currTask[i]] += x.extraFreq[i];
                }
                else
                    x.freqArr[x.currTask[i]] = x.extraFreq[i];
                
                // Update entropy in struct and current frequency
                x.currH[i] = H;
                currFreq += x.extraFreq[i];
            }
            
            // Send entropies back to client
            for (int i = 0; i < x.currH.size(); i++)
            {
                n = write(newsockfd, &x.currH[i], sizeof(x.currH[i]));
                if (n < 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error writing to socket" << std::endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            close(newsockfd);
        }
    }
close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `accept()` in the server, then forking off a child and calling `accept()` again in it instead of handling the first new connection?

Comment: A `std::string` doesn't (necessarily) directly contain the contents of the string. It often contains a pointer to the data, which will be allocated on the free store. So just copying a `std::string` object over a socket is going to give the receiver a pointer to an address that's only valid on the client. You probably want to copy the contents of the string over the socket (and typically prefix it with its length, so the receiver knows how much data goes into the string). The receiver will then create its own string from that data.

Comment: You pass a pointer to a `std::vector<threadInfo>` to `pthread_create`, but your thread function seems to expect a `threadInfo` instead. That's gonna give you a bad time. Didn't you mean `&info[i]`?

Comment: In the client code, your `info` vector is empty when you  try to fill `info[i]`. That is *undefined behavior*. Also, `pthread_t tid[strings.size()];` is a variable-length array, which is [not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Use `std::vector` instead. But why are you creating a separate array of thread IDs at all.? You could just put your `pthread_t` into your `threadInfo` struct instead.

Comment: First thing you need to do when observing a segfault is to determine which line of code is causing the fault.  You can do that with a debugger, or (if you prefer the low-tech approach) by sprinkling temporary debug-prints around your code and seeing which ones get printed out just before the crash and which ones don't get printed out (because the program crashed before execution got to them).  Once you know which line is crashing, you'll probably have a good idea about *why* it's crashing as well.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use pthreads? Why not `std:: jthread`? It has safer API, reducing risk of trivial mistakes. Using `std::memcpy` generally signifies poor design; you don't need it using STL instead of raw arrays.